# Changing Twitter logo in twitter feed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, widget

Hi I have a twitter feed using the following code:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
        <script>
        new TWTR.Widget({
          version: 2,
          type: 'profile',
          rpp: 3,
          interval: 6000,
          width: 195,
          height: 300,
          theme: {
            shell: {
              background: '#999999',
              color: '#D6E03D'
            },
            tweets: {
              background: '#f3f3f3',
              color: '#999999',
              links: '#5a5a5a'
            }
          },
          features: {
            scrollbar: false,
            loop: false,
            live: false,
            hashtags: true,
            timestamp: true,
            avatars: false,
            behavior: 'all'
          }
        }).render().setUser('louise').start();


        </script>
```

and this is linked to the widget.js file. I need the default twitter to be blue not white so I tried downloading the js file and hosting it from my server and changing the code to my image using this code:

```
isFullScreen?" twtr-fullscreen":""}var AA=T?"images/widget-logoblue.png":"http://widgets.twimg.com/i/widget-logo.png";
```

this adds the blue image in ok but it messes up some of the links that should be different colours within the feed, therefore I think I need to stick to linking to this version:

```
isFullScreen?" twtr-fullscreen":""}var AA=T?"images/widget-logoblue.png":"http://widgets.twimg.com/i/widget-logo.png";
```

is there a way I can link to this but override the twitter image that they are using with my own twitter logo?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks
Louise

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution might be one of these:

1. CSS hack - hide image and use background-image CSS property instead
2. Detect image on load and replace it then
3. Write a custom widget. [Example](https://github.com/bebraw/codegrove-site/blob/gh-pages/js/twitter.js).